# Sharepoint 2013 workflows are not getting started

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

- I have a SharePoint 2013 designer workflows configured with the start options as 'Manual'.
- It was working fine for few weeks. However one fine day, the workflow fails to get started. Even when I tried manually starting the workflow I got an error like "***Sorry, Something went wrong. To try again, reload the page & then start the workflow***".

After reading the below blogs, I found out the solution could be restarting the 'Service Bus Gateway' and 'Service Bus Message Broker'

- [Andre connell blog](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/Troubleshooting-Publishing-and-Executing-Workflows-in-SP2013-Beta-2)
- [Link 2](http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/azure/workflow.aspx?ID=0483c876-a2e9-4f2e-91b7-e3337e67cd34)

**Question**

1. Have anyone come across this and identified the root cause of the issue?